# How to send contents of Listview to another Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

I have a RelativeLayout with two TextViews inside it,the layout looks like a button. The user presses the "button" and I send one of the TextViews to a resulting TextView and the second TextView I put in a list. This is all done on the same activity. The user can keep pressing the "button" and it will populate the ListView with many items. My question is how do I send what's been populated in that resulting TextView and the ListView to a new activity. I'm able to send contents of the resulting TextView just fine but not getting anywhere with sending the contents of the ListView to new Activity.

This is the first Activity

```
public class MenuView1Activity extends ListActivity {

private double overallTotalproduct;
public static TextView resultTextView;

ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

private Button whateverButton;
       TextView inputPrice;
       RelativeLayout lay1;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menuview);

        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                listItems);
                setListAdapter(adapter);

whateverButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.whateverButton);
inputPrice= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
lay1= (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.lay1);


//Total Box
    final TextView textViewtotalproduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);

final TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.m1aa);
    final String stringm1aa = textView1.getText().toString();
    final double intm1aa = Double.parseDouble(stringm1aa);
    final TextView textView1a = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.m1a);
    final String stringm1a = textView1a.getText().toString();

lay1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listItems.add("$"+intm1aa +"-"+ stringm1a);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            resultTextView.setText(stringm1a);
            overallTotalproduct =  intm1aa + overallTotalproduct;
            textViewtotalproduct.setText(String.valueOf(overallTotalproduct));
        }
    });

public void onwhateverPress(View v) {
Intent whateverIntent = new Intent(this, WhateverActivity.class);

if (whateverResult.iswhateveranicewhatever()) {

final TextView daplane =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);
String watch = daplane.getText().toString();



startActivity(new Intent(MenuView1Activity.this,RecordCheckActivity.class)
.putExtra("date",(CharSequence)watch)
.putStringArrayListExtra("list", (ArrayList<String>) listItems));
finish();
```

And the Second one

```
    Intent id11 = getIntent();
    if (id11.getCharSequenceExtra("list") != null) {
    final TextView setmsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.saleNotes);
    setmsg.setText(id11.getCharSequenceExtra("list"));              

    }
```

Comment: Can you explain " not getting anywhere with sending the contents of the ListView to new Activity"?

Comment: I'm not receiving any errors but the data from ListView is not showing up in the second activity either.

Comment: Are you talking about `listItems`?

Comment: Yes, listItems are not showing up on the next activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get all updated items from ListView using `ListView.getAdapter()` then use `Intent.putStringArrayListExtra` for sending ArrayList from one Activity to other:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MenuView1Activity.this,RecordCheckActivity.class)
.putExtra("date",(CharSequence)watch)
.putStringArrayListExtra("list", (ArrayList<String>)getListView().getAdapter()));
finish();
```

Comment: I'm receiving a ClassCastException error right on line .putStringArrayListExtra("list", (ArrayList<String>)getListView().getAdapter()));

Comment: The actual error is 06-06 21:49:27.811: E/AndroidRuntime(11505): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=13274384, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxx.MenuView1Activity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ArrayAdapter